# How do I code for my app to access contacts in device?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, contacts

How do messaging apps like WhatsApp or Signal or any app , get access to contacts , camera and all. I'm building a web chat application using JavaScript , NodeJS . I want my app to access contacts of the device . How do I write code to do that for me ??

Comment: You cannot access local information using JavaScript running from a website, that would be a major security issue as any web page could just take all of your contacts if you visited it once.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons web browsers are restricted access to the devices they're running on. You wouldn't want a web page to gain access to your hard drive or emails now would you! The reason WhatsApp and Signal can do it is that they are not running in a web browser.

If you are going down the Javascript route I would recommend looking in to React Native. It is ReactJS but for mobile devices. It is cross platform and allows web-app developers to use their skills on mobile platforms.

[Check it out here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started)